# padding and margin should set to 0 as inline style

Tags: php, html, css, templates

Im not designer, I tried to send mail from php, so i have taken one template and converted all styles to inline but where to include below universal margin and padding style in template

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

If i use above code it is not reflecting in mail, how to write as inline style ?

Comment: php don't know padding margin

Comment: How about try a premailer such as http://premailer.dialect.ca/ . `*` means all elements

Comment: You have to add it to each relevant html tag as an inline style, like you just said that you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the inline style on `<body>` tag

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<!-- Code -->
</body>
```